# Is a listview with webview items appropriate for a news app?

Tags: android, listview

I am building an app that scrapes a certain web site and presents the latest news in a listview, html formattted with an image, a title and a summary. When the user clicks on a row, the news article is showed. It works a bit like the CNet app and similar news apps.

I have no problems with the scraping part, but I am in doubt on how to manage the summary list.

My initial idea is to have a listview where each item is a webview. The listview is populated by a custom ArrayAdapter filled with the scraped html content. Each screen will show the summaries from the 30 most recent articles, ie. up to a month old.

Is this approach recommended or will 30 webviews take up too many system resources?

Would it actually be better to use on big webview, using simple html (ul) to show the summary list?

Also, is an array adaptor the right way to go, or would a cursor be better?

If there are completely different ways to do this, please let me know!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webview is not a bad approach, but there are better ways. I'd suggest to show the text normally (I mean, in a `TextView`). I'd use `WebView` if you are going to show long HTML content that has a complex format or use CSS... but, what you want is showing a preview, so keep it simple. It will be also faster, and more maintainable if you do it in a `TextView`.

With regards to the adapter... it really depends on how are you persisting the data. If you are just fetching those feeds from internet, parsing them and showing them right away, then you have no choice but using an `ArrayAdapter` or something like that. On the other hand, if you are persisting your data into a Sqlite database, then `CursorAdapter` is much better.

Comment: Hmmm, I could perhaps use a webview and Html.fromHtml() for simple formatting... Regarding the persistence of data, to be honest I haven't really thought about that. But you're right, it should probably be cached to save bandwidth. The content is not likely to change, but I could implement an update action in case the user wants fresh data.

Comment: You are right. I used three normal textviews, for title, date and summary. For the summary very simple formatting like bold and italic using Html.fromHtml() works just fine! When the user clicks on a summary to see the full article, that is shown in webview in another activity.

Answer (score 2):

Romain Guy, the developer on the Android team who is most vocal on the web helping developers actually said in one of his talks (which you can find on YouTube...not sure which one) that technically you "could" do that, but he'd be extremely upset with you if you did.  lol

There is probably too much going on in a WebView to make this the ideal choice of ListView items.  I would create a "model" object representing the data for each item that you're abstracting and just make an xml layout that you can populate in a custom adapter.

This video is GREAT info if you're working with ListView

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Thanks for recommending this fine video

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the application wouldn't be able to handle the 30 html feeds, so you should be good there.

A ListView should be fine to use.  Obviously, this all depends on how you want the UI to look and feel.

Lastly, a cursor adapter is used when using a cursor from a db query.   Unless you're storing the feeds in a local db, this doesn't seem to be what you're doing.  So, the array adapter should work fine for you.